# Is this figure overfitting?

Tags: python, machine-learning

Is it overfitting in the case of a plot like the figure?

I was not very familiar with overfitting and did research, but I couldn't determine if this figure was overfitting.

So please let me know if you are familiar with overfitting.

I would be happy if you could tell me why.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Here is a good explanation of overfitting:
https://elitedatascience.com/overfitting-in-machine-learning
But to me it looks like your model is not overfitting as your train and test loss is very close to each other.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Deep learning overfitting", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  Stack Overflow is not intended as a tutorial resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not overfitting. Overfitting (in basic terms) means that model over-adjusts its parameters, or uses features that only apply to an specific set of training data in order to have the best accuracy possible for the train sample, while having a poor test/validation accuracy. The plot does not show overfitting because both train_loss and test_loss functions behave in a similar fashion.

Here is an example of a NN I was working on, I set way too many features for the model, and ended up making the model overfit a lot. 
**How can you tell?** Because there is huge difference in performance when comparing the acc (train accuracy) with the val_acc (validation/test accuracy). In order to achieve best performance with your model, you want it to have the best test or validation accuracy possible while keeping a good train accuracy too, this means the model generalizes well, because it performs good independent of the sample/data it is given.

[image: Overfitting example]

Comment: The plots you've shown there are not a case of clear overfit. The overfit is more than when your model learn to map your train input data to train labels lossing the generalización. In the case of clear overfitting your test loss will incrementaly increases while your train loss decreases. In your plot your train and test loss mantains the same difference along the epochs. That could be interpreted as your model not only learns the general distribution or your data, It also learns specific patterns of your train data that doesn't appear again on your test data.

Comment: In the most extreme cases of overfitting, yes, one will increase while the other will decrease. In the plots I show, it is easy to find x-values where acc is increasing and val_acc decreasing, let alone the big difference between both. And this is part of what happens when you get overfitting,yes: "That could be interpreted as your model not only learns the general distribution or your data, It also learns specific patterns of your train data that doesn't appear again on your test data."

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!
Thanks to you, I was able to deepen my understanding of overfitting!
I will do my best using this knowledge!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah, if you take the meaning of overfit literaly, of course there is a clear overfitting problem. But, what I want to express is that there probably is not a problem of your model that causes that difference. Usually in cases like that, where the distant of those curves is more or less constant, the problem is the data. Can happen that your train data is easier to predict or there are some lack of examples that cause your model not able to cover all the problem aspects. Check the link provided in the comment below.

Comment: Not in this case. I have the full code I could share with you and in comparison to another model which got me over 90% of val_acc, the main issue was the amount of neurons I was using in each layer and learning rate. With the same data, and activation functions I could improve the model to reduce overfitting achiving an almost 90% accuracy for the validation data.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the case of `overfitting`.If its overfitting... `training loss<< validation loss`!. There will be lot of gap between both.Here the lines seems to be close

Here is a [good example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/learning-curves-for-diagnosing-machine-learning-model-performance/)

Comment: Not always that it happens is a case of overfit. But the example you provide is a very good example.

Comment: Why is that its not always, thats an interesting info.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me concise and easy for me!
I can think more intuitively thanks to this answer!

Comment: I try yo explain in the other answer.